# Moodle 2.8.3 Log out Problems

Tags: logout, moodle

Recently my school upgraded to Moodle 2.8.3 and now I can't figure out how to log out. This is really bugging me. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Click on your user icon in the top-right corner of the page and then select 'Log out' from the drop down.

This assumes your school hasn't installed a custom theme that does something different with the menu.